# Are variables passed to a python function thread safe?

Tags: python

Not new to python but this is something that has bugged me for a while. If I pass mystring as a string into a funtion:

```
def func(mystring):
     print(mystring)
     #do other things to mystring
```

And func is called by many threads, is mystring thread safe? or can its value be changed when another thread calls the func ?

My thoughts are that it should not be since mystring is immutable. I understand that mutable objects are not thread safe but how about immutable objects?

Comment: It's impossible to say anything about thread safety (except a very conservative "no") unless you provide a lot more information about the code you're asking about.

Comment: Integers are immutable yet not thread safe.

Comment: You may find [this post](https://www.quora.com/Are-local-variables-in-a-python-function-thread-safe) useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully I'll be corrected if I'm wrong but I believe the answer is **yes** - `mystring` is thread-safe. From [this post](https://www.quora.com/Are-local-variables-in-a-python-function-thread-safe):

> Local variables are certainly "thread-exclusive." No other thread can access them directly, and this is helpful but not sufficient to guarantee semantic thread safety.
>
> A local variable in one thread does not store its value in the same location as the same-named local variable in another thread.
>
> This is basically a direct consequence of the definition of functions and local variables. More or less every structured programming language does something like the following:
>
> - Every time a function is invoked, a new block of memory called a stack frame is allocated (and it becomes invalid/destroyed when the function returns).
> - Local variables' values are stored within that stack frame.

As a local variable, each thread that calls `func` will be storing the value of `mystring` in a location that no other thread can access. The article goes on to point out that thread-exclusivity is *necessary* but not *sufficient* to ensure thread-safety:

> However, guaranteeing that two threads have separate storage for local variables is not enough to ensure thread-safety, because those local variables can refer to globally shared data in a thread-unsafe way.

In this case however, you are not depending on or modifying any globally shared data; `mystring` references a string object that is only locally-accessible and immutable to boot.

Between the thread-exclusivity and the absence of interaction/dependence on global state, I believe it's thread-safe.

Comment: This is my thoughts too. And from my experiments it seems you are correct. mystring changes do not show in other threads. However if mystring was a mutable object and i modify a property of it, it looks like the passed object is modified since python  is pass by reference. But what bugs me is each thread however does not see the change even if it is mutable.